# If a 3x3 matrix is diagonalizable and has eigenvalues 1,2 but has 2 eigenvectors with eigenvalue 2, would we...

Tags: linear-algebra

If a $3 \times 3$ matrix is diagonalizable and has eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ but has two eigenvectors with eigenvalue $2$, would we have the eigenvalue matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: Yes, that is one possibility. Of course you can permute the diagonal elements of the diagonal matrix

Comment: @Stefan ahh, I just wanted to know whether you entered in the value 2 twice for each of the eigenvectors

Comment: Are the eigenvectors, with eigenvalue 2, linearly independent?

Comment: Also note that both eigenvectors for the eigenvalue 2 have to be linear independent.

Comment: They are, but what if that wasn't the case?

Comment: For a matrix to be diagonalizable, $\mathbb R^3$ has to be the direct sum of the eigenspaces. From this it follows, that if you have 2 eigenvalues, one of the two eigenspaces has to have dimension 2, and thus there have to exist two linear independent eigenvectors to that eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Since the linear operator described by this matrix acts on 3-dimensional space, and is known to have

- a one-dimensional eigenspace for eigenvalue $1$, and
- two-dimensional eigenspace for eigenvalue 2,

it is correct to conclude that the space has a basis composed of eigenvectors, and in this   basis the operator has the matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
up to permutation of rows.

---

If both eigenspaces turned out to be one-dimensional, the Jordan canonical form of this matrix could have been 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
or 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
$$